# Cross-site POST form submissions are forbidden

Tags: node.js, post, backend, svelte, sveltekit

My sveltekit app has a form which sends a POST request to server. The app is working fine on dev server but when I build and run the app it fails to send the form data via POST request. It shows the following error in the browser:

> Cross-site POST form submissions are forbidden

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to set the the ORIGIN env var like this

`ORIGIN=http://localhost:3000 node build/index.js`

https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-node#origin-protocol_header-and-host_header

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Also for anyone who's setting enviroment variables in powershell, `$env:ORIGIN = "http://127.0.0.1"` and run `node build/index.js` on the next line, because for some reason, powershell does not notice the change in env var when the env var is changed and the build command is run on the same line.

Comment: What about `import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';` ? how to fix this error with adapter-auto..

Comment: You can also set an environment variable `ORIGIN` when you deploy your app (for example when using Docker).
Note that it is important whether you use `https://example.com` or `https://www.example.com` when setting the origin.

Comment: you may need to benefit from node-adaptor if you are using sveltekit with latest version https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node

Comment: I have a .com site and a .org site. Using nginx to point both to the same app. Should I be redirecting to one or the other instead? Because if I specify ORIGIN to be one domain, POST requests won't be available on the other domain

Answer (score 15):

This is a built-in protection against [cross-site request forgery attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf) in Sveltekit. Set `csrf` to `false` in `svelte.config.js` to allow cross-site post requests.

See [csrf](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#csrf) in the Sveltekit [configuration docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration)

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node'

const config = {
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter(),
    csrf: {
      checkOrigin: false,
    }
  },
}

export default config
```

Comment: I would _not_ advise to do this! CSRF attacks are a real thing and its important to have a protection against them.

See the answer below by evan for the correct way to do it - you have to tell the sveltekit server about the actual origin domain when you start your sveltekit application.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using PM2 as process manager, it is similar with:

```
ORIGIN=https://yourapp.com pm2 restart /var/www/build/index.js --name 'yourapp' --update-env
```

Answer (score 3):

This works: `node -r dotenv/config build` after including your new variable in .env `ORIGIN=https://yourwebsite.com` (please install it with `npm install dotenv` command as pointed out [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-node#environment-variables))

Comment: Now it doesn't after updating it. Something may go wrong and it doesn't restart the serever, thus not loading origin as your domain

Comment: After several days, checked .env variables if they are loaded correctly, seems origin is undefined: process.env.ORIGIN. 

Check all of them `console.log(process.env)`

Answer (score 1):

My Svelte app is deployed in Docker so, I just needed to add the `ORIGIN` environment variable to the Dockerfile, by adding the following line:

`ENV ORIGIN https://mywebsite.com`

This environment variable can also be added on the docker-compose.yml file, by doing the following:

```
environment:
  - ORIGIN=https://mywebsite.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else arrives here after all this time, there's a slightly simpler solution, for cases like mine anyway: the `csrf` check will not be invoked if the submission doesn't have a `Content-Type` header that looks like a form. From the code, this function needs to return true to enable the check:

```js
function is_form_content_type(request) {
  return is_content_type(
    request,
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "multipart/form-data",
    "text/plain"
  );
}
```

In my case I am working on a backend server api, so setting `Content-Type` to `application/json` allowed the request to proceed.

Note this is SvelteKit server code, and is not dependant on the adapter you're using.